# Is it possible to "hard-code" a user stylesheet (.css) into a webview activity inside an Android app?

Tags: android, css, webview, android-webview

Is it possible from within an Android app, with WebView, to provide, and enforce the use of a css-file, just like the way userContent.css works in Firefox?

Background: I need, as part of an app, to display webpages that I don't have control over the sourcecode and want to style them from within the app.

Basically, I can't touch the webpages but could, via an external css, make them fit my theme. (It's boring documentation, nothing sexy yet, but it has to reflect the CI.)

I'd appreciate any hint as the docs aren't exactly helpful, in this case. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really know if you can so this may not be helpful but I once had to do something similar. I just saved the html file to a string, parsed the head and stuck in the css file below any other style tags, then loaded the webview with the html string. Not really an answer but it is something that worked for me. May not suit your situation.

Comment: Thanks, Ruairi; that's an interesting solution but in this case, it doesn't suit the application. I'll keep this in mind for other cases, though.